# Unable to call Squish functions in Python modules

Tags: windows, python-2.7, squish

Problem: Unable to call squish functions in Python modules. Imported squish & added squish. in front of its function but doesn't seem to work.

test.py

```
import gAPI 

screenshot(obj, filename)
```

gAPI.py

```
import squish 

def screenshot(obj, file): 
    widget = squish.waitForObject(obj) 
    img = squish.grabWidget(widget) 
    img.squish.save(file,"PNG") 
return img
```

When this is ran in Python modules it returns the error "QPixmap" Squish object has no attribute "squish". Wonder if anyone knows how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell it should be...

```
img.save(file,"PNG")
```

...instead.

The fact that the QPixmap type is located in module "squish" does not mean that ".squish" needs to be added to calls of its methods/functions. So this works the same as for any other Python type.